# What does it mean to make a function continuous?

Tags: calculus, continuity

Can we make $\frac{\sin (x+y)}{x+y}$ continuous, defining it appropriately at $(0, 0)$ ??

What does it mean to make a function continuous??

Comment: You only want to define it at $(0,0)$?  Or do you want to define it at all $(x,-x)$?

Comment: Simply put, a continuous function $f(x)$ means that there are no breaks or cuts in the curve $y=f(x)$

Comment: The exercise asks at $(0, 0)$. But what does it mean to make a function continuous?? @ThomasAndrews

Comment: The question is whether $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y}$ exists. If it does, then you can define a function which is equal to the given one where that is defined and equal to that limit at $(0,0)$. (Of course there is still concern about, e.g., $(1,-1)$.)

Comment: But what does it mean to MAKE a function continuous?? @PrasunBiswas

Comment: An informal version is, "A function $f(x)$ is continuous if you can draw the curve $y=f(x)$ in a single go without lifting your pen from the plane of paper.

Comment: Well, making a function continuous can be thought of as finding suitable values of unknown constants in a function such that the limit definition of continuity holds.

Comment: You make a function (take for instance $g(x) = \frac{x^3 + y^3}{x^2 + y^2}$) continuous by writing down a piecewise definition of it, like this:
$$
g(x) = \cases{\frac{x^3 + y^3}{x^2 + y^2} & for $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$\\0 & for $(x, y) = 0$}
$$
but in your case you have a whole _line_ of singularities to worry about, not just the origin.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Calculus books often play fast and loose with domains (and targets), but it's important to realize (and remember) that changing the domain of a function, *even by adding or removing a single point*, gives a *different function*. This is a mildly pedantic answer, but taking extra care may be worthwhile. Here are some relevant definitions:

If $X$ is a set, $A \subset X$, and $f:A \to \Reals$ is a function, then an *extension* of $f$ to $X$ is a function $F:X \to \Reals$ such that
$$
F(x) = f(x)\quad\text{for all $x$ in $A$.}
$$
(In other words, the *restriction* of $F$ to $A$ is $f$.)

A *continuous extension* of $f$ to $X$ is exactly what it sounds like: An extension of $f$ to $X$ that is, in addition, continuous.

Here $A = \{(x, y)\text{ in } \Reals^{2} : x + y \neq 0\}$ is the plane $\Reals^{2}$ with the line $y = -x$ removed; $X = A \cup \{(0, 0)\}$ is the set $A$ with the origin appended, and $f:A \to \Reals$ is defined by
$$
f(x, y) = \frac{\sin(x + y)}{x + y}.
$$
The question amounts to: Does there exist a *continuous extension* of $f$ to $X$? Informally, "can $f(0, 0)$ be defined in such a way that $f$ is continuous at $(0, 0)$?"

The answer *in this example* boils down to, "Does $\lim\limits_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y)$ exist?" If "yes", and if the limit is $\ell$, then defining $f(0, 0) = \ell$ gives a continuous extension of $f$ to $X$. If "no", $f$ has no continuous extension to $X$.

---

(Incidentally, as a couple of commenters have noted, the origin is not the only "problem point" for $f$. Is it possible that
$$
f(x, y) = \frac{\sin(x^{2} + y^{2})}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\quad\text{or}\quad
f(x, y) = \frac{\sin\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}}
$$
instead? The latter two functions are defined everywhere except the origin.)

Answer (score 0):

A function is continuous (in a domain) if it is continuous at every point of its domain. Saying this is equivalent as to saying that $$\lim_{\textbf {x} \to a} f(\textbf  x) = f(\textbf a)$$ for every $a \in Dom f$.

Once you have this in mind, you need to estabilish your domain, and see that your function fulfills the requirements.

Answer (score -1):

A function is continuous if for every $x$ in it's domain, it is true that:
$$
\lim_{y\to x}f(y)=f(x)
$$
This is the same as the curve being drawable with a pencil.

To make a function continuous, would probably mean that the function is not defined at, say $0$ because of division by zero, and then you figure out which value you could define the function to have at that point, such that the resulting function is continuous.

Comment: Pedantically speaking, it's not really possible to draw a non-rectifiable curve with a pencil...

Comment: Regarding your second claim, the "drawable with a pencil" criterion is actually [technically wrong](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173342/shouldnt-this-function-be-discontinuous-everywhere/1173456#1173456). In addition, a function of _two_ variables (as in the OP's question) can "have its graph in one piece" and still be discontinuous. (That isn't the case here, but it's a logical possibility at the outset.) :)